# Cheerio Will Not Parse Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

For some reason my code is not working. I've tried everything and have ensured that cheerio is indeed loading. For whatever reason, the foreach loop does not execute.

The jQuery itself works and has been tested in the browser. No errors are thrown. All I get back is a response of an empty urls array.

ex: []

```
const getHTML = (url) => {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, (err, res, html) => {
            (err) ? reject(err) : resolve(html)
        })
    })
    return promise;
}

const grabPages = (html) => {

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var urls = []
        var $ = cheerio.load(html)

        $(".tdname a").each(function (i, el) {
            var $el = $(el)
            console.log($el)
            urls.push($el.href)
        });

        resolve(urls);
    })
    return promise;
}

const exec = () => {
    return getHTML('http://fakesite.net')
        .then(grabPages).then(res => console.log(res))
}

module.exports = exec;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I feel really dumb now. Before expecting cheerio to return any results, please ensure that the dom element you are going to use is actually loaded onto the page.

The element I was trying to manipulate was loaded in via AJAX and because of this, cheerio did not find the element.

This did not throw any errors so please take caution before wasting hours of your life like I did.